# Selecting multiple buttons from map function in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm trying to select multiple options from the map function but i cant seem to generate logic to do so, i'm selecting a button and that button is generating a heading and a text felid in a scrollview with the lable of button as heading, but now i want to select multiple buttons to generate multiple components:

Any logic and help would be great please, m stuck!

here is code for refrence:

**this is usestate and  buttonLabels array:**

```
  
    const handlePress = (index) => 
    {
      setSelectedButtonIndex(index === selectedButtonIndex ? null : index);
    };
  
    const buttonLabels = [
      'Homeowner',
      'In-depth',
      'Inherited',
      'Probate',
      'Lost income',
      'Relocation',
      'Divorce',
      'Downsizing'
    ];
```

**and here is the map function:**

```
        {/* List of Items */}
        <View style={styles.buttonGrid}>
          {buttonLabels.map((label, index) => (
            <TouchableOpacity
              key={index}
              style={[
                styles.button,
                { backgroundColor: index === selectedButtonIndex ? '#346284' : '#FFFFFF' },
              ]}
              onPress={() => handlePress(index)}
            >
              <Text style={{ color: index === selectedButtonIndex ? '#FFFFFF' : '#888889' }}>
                {label}
              </Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          ))}
        </View>
```

**and here i'm generate component at the selectedbutton**

```
       <ScrollView style={{flexGrow:2}}>
            {selectedButtonIndex !== undefined && (
            <View style={styles.headingContainer}>
                <View style={styles.heading}>
                <Text style={styles.headingText}>{buttonLabels[selectedButtonIndex]}</Text>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => setSelectedButtonIndex(undefined)}>
                    <Image source={require('../assets/Icons/close.png')} style={styles.closeIcon} />
                </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
                <TextInput style={styles.textInput} placeholder="Enter Text Here" />
            </View>
            )}
        </ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to choose multiple item,

```
let array=[{"option":"option1",selected:false}, {"option":"option1",selected:false}]
```

based on index or item you need to change the boolean value, then show when the boolean value is true show the item example ,

onpress function like

```
const onselect=(selectedIndex)=>{
  let temp=array //local array
  temp.map((item,index)=>{
    if(index==selectedIndex) item.selected=!item.selected
  })
  setState([...temp]) //set your local state
```

})

in render method,

```
array.map((item,index)=>{if(item.selected) <View></View>})
```